# Drawing a LineSeries chart in QML

Tags: javascript, qt, charts, qml

I'm new in Qt/QML and I need to draw a charts in QML with a formatTime on the axis X (for example: 00:05 (the format is hh:mm)). In the Qt Documentation I found an example:

```
    ChartView {
    title: "Accurate Historical Data"
    anchors.fill: parent
    legend.visible: false
    antialiasing: true

    LineSeries {
        axisX: DateTimeAxis {
            format: "yyyy MMM"
            tickCount: 5
        }
        axisY: ValueAxis {
            min: 0
            max: 150
        }

        // Please note that month in JavaScript months are zero based, so 2 means March
        XYPoint { x: toMsecsSinceEpoch(new Date(1950, 2, 15)); y: 5 }
        XYPoint { x: toMsecsSinceEpoch(new Date(1970, 0, 1)); y: 50 }
        XYPoint { x: toMsecsSinceEpoch(new Date(1987, 12, 31)); y: 102 }
        XYPoint { x: toMsecsSinceEpoch(new Date(1998, 7, 1)); y: 100 }
        XYPoint { x: toMsecsSinceEpoch(new Date(2012, 8, 2)); y: 110 }
    }
}

// DateTimeAxis is based on QDateTimes so we must convert our JavaScript dates to
// milliseconds since epoch to make them match the DateTimeAxis values
function toMsecsSinceEpoch(date) {
    var msecs = date.getTime();
    return msecs;
}
```

How can I set the values of the axis X with a time instead of a date?
Your help would be much appreciated

Comment: May be `format: "HH:mm"`? See [QDateTime::toString()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#toString) for complete format reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the (more) exact time just in the `Date` constructor.

```
XYPoint{ x: toMsSinceEpoch(new Date(2017, 9, 27, 15, 29, 21)), y: 5 }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Then you can set the X axis format to display hours and seconds:

```
DateTimeAxis {
    ....
    format: "hh:mm"
}
```